# Custom fonts not loading in iframe

Tags: css, iframe, font-face

- I have an iframe, and none of the custom fonts that I'm applying via the stylesheet are loading (the font is correctly applied in the stylesheet, it just doesn't work).
- I'm trying to add the styles in the actual iframe, not from the parent page
- The font is being correctly defined in the stylesheet (and I'm applying the various different font types e.g. .eot .otf .woff and .svg).
- I've also correctly configured the mime types for the font in my web.config, and the fonts are on the server in the correct location (I'm hosting the actual fonts).
- There are no errors in the 'console' of the browser
- In the 'net' tab in Firefox, there are no failed loads for any files
- The fonts don't load on any browser

Any ideas what's going on or anything else I should check?

Here's the font declaration in the stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TradeGothicLTBdCondTwenty';
    src: url('../fonts/lte50543.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lte50543.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lte50543.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lte50543.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/lte50543.svg#TradeGothicLTBdCondTwenty') format('svg');       
}
```

and here's the staticContent section of the web.config that allows the file types:

```
<staticContent>
    <!-- HTML5 Web font MIMEtypes -->
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <!-- Proper SVG Serving -->
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".svgz" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Did u check if browser try to load a non existing ressource in Inspector Networkpanel?

Comment: Did you specify the stylesheet with the fonts in the framed page?

Comment: Josh, thanks, although no, not a duplicate question - I'm trying to add the styles in the actual iframe, not from the parent page.  I've edited the question to clarify this

Comment: Thanks Bernhard - I've checked and edited my question to clarify that in the 'net' tab in Firefox, there are no failed loads for any files

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow Not sure why someone downvoted - 1+ To counter it though.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this.  We're using the TFS (Team Foundation Server) build system to deploy the site, and the TFS build action for the fonts wasn't set to 'copy if newer', so when the site was redeployed, the fonts had actually been removed from the server (I'd previously had to deploy them manually for testing purposes on the server).